# Using document.getElementById() inside object, works in JSFiddle, TypeError in actual. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I have a code that works in JSFiddle but doesn't work when I save the HTML+JS locally and test it locally. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. Here is my JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LLUAB/

And here is the actual code, not very long

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
function Composer(foobox) {
    this.foobox = document.getElementById(foobox);

    this.foobox.onkeydown = function(){window.alert("hello")};
}

var myComposer = new Composer("foo");
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="foo"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you’re looking for the _opposite_ problem — i.e. the code works locally, but not in JSFiddle — see [Why isn't my JavaScript working in JSFiddle?](/q/5431351/4642212). Both behaviors have the same cause: JSFiddle automatically wraps JS code in a function that is executed as soon as the DOM is ready, which also causes `onclick` to be out of scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in JSFiddle your script is placed inside `window.onLoad` event handler by default. While in your case `getElementById()` method is unable to find not yet loaded element.

Put all your script right before closing `</body>` tag and it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Doh!! Duh! Of course! That has to be the one thing I keep forgetting, that unless I wrap it in an onLoad, the script runs before the DOM exists >.< thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works in Fiddle because of `onLoad` option specified here. The problem is that when `new Composer` line is fired, there's no such element in the DOM yet. Wrap this line in `DOMReady` handler - or move its invokation to the end of `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your dom is not ready yet

```
function Composer(foobox) {
    this.foobox = document.getElementById(foobox);
    alert(this.foobox); --Prints null
    this.foobox.onkeydown = function(){window.alert("hello")};
}
```

Working code here. http://jsfiddle.net/LLUAB/1/